# The Win32 API procedure of drag-and-dropping a file from my app to another app

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-core, pinvoke

In short, trying to do what the following two lines of C# code do without using `System.Windows.Forms`, because it is .NET Core and not a WinForms project.

```
var data = new System.Windows.Forms.DataObject(
    System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop, new string[] { @"C:\test.txt"});
dummyControl.DoDragDrop(data, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

But it does not work. What have I done wrong? My procedure was,

1. When mouse is down on a UI control, call `SetCapture` to capture the event.
2. The `IDropSource`'s `QueryContinueDrag` keep returning `S_OK` until the mouse button is up, and then `DRAGDROP_S_DROP`.
3. My "DataObject" implementing `IDataObject` has `EnumFormatEtc`. In which I return only one `FORMATETC`.

   ```
       new FORMATETC()
       {
           cfFormat = CF_HDROP,
           ptd = IntPtr.Zero,
           dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_ICON,
           lindex = -1,
           tymed = TYMED.TYMED_FILE
       }
   ```

   4. In `QueryGetData`, if the `format`'s `tymed` is `TYMED_FILE`, return `S_OK` meaning I am dragging a file. Otherwise return `DV_E_TYMED` meaning I don't have that type of data.
   5. In `GetData`, if the `format`'s `tymed` is `TYMED_FILE`, I set a file like this

      ```
          medium = new STGMEDIUM();
          medium.tymed = TYMED.TYMED_FILE;
          medium.unionmember = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(@"C:\test.txt");
          medium.pUnkForRelease = IntPtr.Zero;
      ```

I tried to drag-and-drop to Notepad. Problems are,

1. When `DoDragDrop` is not called on the mouse down event, mouse is captured and mouse up event is received. But when `DoDragDrop` is called, `QueryContinueDrag` is endlessly called and I don't get the mouse up event, even after I released the mouse. I tried to call `DoDragDrop` in another thread, but that did not work.
2. I get callbacks like `QueryGetData(TYMED_HGLOBAL)` or `QueryGetData(TYMED_HGLOBAL, TYMED_ISTREAM, TYMED_GDI, TYMED_MFPICT, TYMED_ENHMF)`, but not for `TYMED_FILE`. Why isn't Notepad requesting that?

The drag and drop seems unnecessarily complex, but for now, I am only interested in dragging a file, so I did not want to implement parts other than that. What in the above procedure or assumptions are wrong?

Comment: Surely you'd prefer updating to .NETCore v3.0, no hacks necessary.

Comment: I knew that .NET Core 3.0 comes with WinForms, but in this case, I am trying to use GTK# for cross-platformness. But, unfortunately, it seemed that GTK# does not support Windows file drag-and-drop (GTK# app to Win32 app). I think I could use WinForms's DoDragDrop even in a GTK# app by creating a dummy `Control`, but doing so could load unnecessary DLLs, so I thought using Win32 API directly would be more efficient. It is just that it is A LOT complicated that I expected.

Comment: That's courageous.  The Mono team tried it but they gave up due to the relentless compatibility problems.  You're having some of that ;)  The [DataObject class](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/DataObject.cs) gets the real job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When DoDragDrop is not called on the mouse down event, mouse is captured and mouse up event is received. But when DoDragDrop is called, QueryContinueDrag is endlessly called and I don't get the mouse up event, even after I released the mouse.

You don't get a mouse up event because `DoDragDrop()` blocks your UI message loop until the drag operation is completed. So you need to use the input flags given to your `QueryContinueDrag()` implementation to decide whether to continue dragging, perform the drop, or abort the operation.

If you start the drag on a left mouse down, return `S_OK` if the `grfKeyState` parameter includes the `MK_LBUTTON` flag, and return `DRAGDROP_S_DROP` if the `MK_LBUTTON` flag is cleared. Return `DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL` if the `fEscapePressed` parameter is true. This is documented on MSDN:

[IDropSource::QueryContinueDrag method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-idropsource-querycontinuedrag)

> Parameters
>
> `fEscapePressed`
>
> **Indicates whether the Esc key has been pressed since the previous call to `QueryContinueDrag` or to `DoDragDrop` if this is the first call to `QueryContinueDrag`**. A `TRUE` value indicates the end user has pressed the escape key; a `FALSE` value indicates it has not been pressed.
>
> `grfKeyState`
>
> **The current state of the keyboard modifier keys on the keyboard.** Possible values can be a combination of any of the flags MK_CONTROL, MK_SHIFT, MK_ALT, MK_BUTTON, **MK_LBUTTON**, MK_MBUTTON, and MK_RBUTTON.
>
> Return Value
>
> This method can return the following values.
>
> S_OK
>   The drag operation should continue. This result occurs if no errors are detected, **the mouse button starting the drag-and-drop operation has not been released**, and the Esc key has not been detected.
>
> DRAGDROP_S_DROP
>   The drop operation should occur completing the drag operation. **This result occurs if `grfKeyState` indicates that the key that started the drag-and-drop operation has been released.**
>
> DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL
>   The drag operation should be canceled with no drop operation occurring. **This result occurs if `fEscapePressed` is TRUE, indicating the Esc key has been pressed.**
>
> Remarks
>
> **The `DoDragDrop` function calls `QueryContinueDrag` whenever it detects a change in the keyboard or mouse button state during a drag-and-drop operation. `QueryContinueDrag` must determine whether the drag-and-drop operation should be continued, canceled, or completed based on the contents of the parameters `grfKeyState` and `fEscapePressed`.**

---

> I get callbacks like QueryGetData(TYMED_HGLOBAL) or QueryGetData(TYMED_HGLOBAL, TYMED_ISTREAM, TYMED_GDI, TYMED_MFPICT, TYMED_ENHMF), but not for TYMED_FILE. Why isn't Notepad requesting that?

You can't use `TYMED_FILE` for `CF_HDROP`, you must use `TYMED_HGLOBAL`. And the content of the allocated `HGLOBAL` must be a [`DROPFILES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-dropfiles) struct followed by a double-null-terminated list of file paths. This is documented on MSDN:

[Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard)

> CF_HDROP
>
> This clipboard format is used when transferring the locations of a group of existing files. Unlike the other Shell formats, it is predefined, so there is no need to call `RegisterClipboardFormat`. **The data consists of an `STGMEDIUM` structure that contains a global memory object. The structure's `hGlobal` member points to a `DROPFILES` structure as its `hGlobal` member.**
>
> **The `pFiles` member of the `DROPFILES` structure contains an offset to a double null-terminated character array that contains the file names.** If you are extracting a `CF_HDROP` format from a data object, you can use `DragQueryFile` to extract individual file names from the global memory object. **If you are creating a `CF_HDROP` format to place in a data object, you will need to construct the file name array.**
>
> **The file name array consists of a series of strings, each containing one file's fully qualified path, including the terminating NULL character. An additional null character is appended to the final string to terminate the array.** For example, if the files `c:\temp1.txt` and `c:\temp2.txt` are being transferred, the character array looks like this:
>
> > `c:\temp1.txt'\0'c:\temp2.txt'\0''\0'`
> >
> > Note
> >     In this example, `'\0'` is used to represent the null character, not the literal characters that should be included.
>
> If the object was copied to the clipboard as part of a drag-and-drop operation, the `pt` member of the `DROPFILES` structure contains the coordinates of the point where the object was dropped. You can use `DragQueryPoint` to extract the cursor coordinates.
>
> If this format is present in a data object, an OLE drag loop simulates `WM_DROPFILES` functionality with non-OLE drop targets. This is important if your application is the source of a drag-and-drop operation on a Windows 3.1 system.

Comment: Thank you. For problem 1, I had skimmed the document and thought it was about keyboard and thus not needed. The argument's description is sort of tricky... For 2, after seeing your answer, I searched Google for an example DROPFILES in C# and found this [existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762222/c-sharp-drag-drop-problem). Using the person's code, I finally got the file drag-and-drop working. Now, the only problem is that the mouse pointer is the "no symbol", instead of a rectangle with a plus sign.

Comment: I got the copy pointer. It turned out that I am responsible for changing the mouse pointer, too. In the `GiveFeedback` callback, I set the copy pointer using Win32 API calls (because .NET's existing cursor code was inside `Windows.Forms`). [This existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485890/using-the-windows-drag-copy-cursor) showed how to load the the copy cursor from "ole32.dll". I wish there were an independent library (not WinForms, WPF, etc) that provides wrappers for Win32 GUI APIs...