# File drag-and-drop using Win32 API is not working on some applications such as File Explorer

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-core, pinvoke, ole

I have implemented [file drag-and-drop using Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798659/the-win32-api-procedure-of-drag-and-dropping-a-file-from-my-app-to-another-app) on a .NET Core app. The problem is, it works with some applications, and not with some other applications.

- Works: Notepad++, Notepad, WordPad, MS Word, Gimp, 7Zip
- Doesn't work: (Windows) File Explorer, Chrome, FireFox, VS Code, Libre Writer, Android Studio

Why is it so?

My "DataObject" implementing IDataObject returns this one `FORMATETC` for `EnumFormatEtc()`. In which I return only one FORMATETC.

```
new FORMATETC()
{
    cfFormat = CF_HDROP,
    ptd = IntPtr.Zero,
    dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_ICON,
    lindex = -1,
    tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL
}
```

On `QueryGetData()`, if the format's tymed is `TYMED_HGLOBAL`, return S_OK meaning I am dragging a file. Otherwise return DV_E_TYMED meaning I don't have that type of data.

On `GetData()` or `GetDataHere()`, if `format.cfFormat == CF_HDROP` and  `format.tymed == TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL`, I filled the `medium` like so:

```
medium = new STGMEDIUM();
medium.tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL;
medium.unionmember = mem;
medium.pUnkForRelease = IntPtr.Zero;
```

, where `mem` is the memory allocated with a `DROPFILES` like so:

```
IntPtr CreateDropFiles(string[] strFiles)
{
    var buffer = new MemoryStream();
    var df = new DROPFILES();
    IntPtr ipGlobal = IntPtr.Zero;
    int bufferLength;

    foreach(var file in strFiles)
    {
        var b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(file);
        buffer.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        buffer.WriteByte(0);
        buffer.WriteByte(0);
    }
    buffer.WriteByte(0);
    bufferLength = (int)buffer.Length;

    // Allocate and get pointer to global memory
    int intTotalLen = Marshal.SizeOf(df) + bufferLength;
    ipGlobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(intTotalLen);

    df.pFiles = Marshal.SizeOf(df);
    df.fWide = true;

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(df, ipGlobal, true);
    var ipNew = new IntPtr(ipGlobal.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(df));
    Marshal.Copy(buffer.ToArray(), 0, ipNew, bufferLength);

    return ipGlobal;
}
```

In contrast, file drag-and-drop to File Explorer or VS Code using WinForm's method like the following worked just fine.

```
var data = new System.Windows.Forms.DataObject(
    System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop,
    new string[] { file1, file2 });
dummy.DoDragDrop(data, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: Have you thought about security issues (UAC)? Two applications not running at the same UAC level cannot communicate (using D&D). So for example, if you run Explorer a standard way (not admin), you cannot D&D with an app running as admin.

Comment: Do some debugging, see which of your methods are being called when you try to drag to those apps, and what they're asking for.

Comment: Not all apps handle `CF_HDROP`. To support a wide range of applications, implement as many [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard) as feasible. The more formats you implement, the more apps you can exchange data with. That said, `DVASPECT_ICON` is the wrong `dwAspect` for `CF_HDROP`, use `DVASPECT_CONTENT`. And your `buffer` is missing a byte, it needs to terminate the string list with a 2-byte null Unicode character, but you are terminating it with a single null byte. You need 2 null bytes, just like at the end of each string.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, I suggest looking at the [source code for `System.Windows.Forms.DataObject`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/DataObject.cs) and see how exactly it implements `System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop`.